# "list index out of range" with lamda function in python and tkinter not showing properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, lambda, label, pulp

The error message when I hit the "forward" button is "list index out of range".

Hi I have been working on this problem for a few weeks now.  With my previous post, someone suggested that I learn how to use lambda function properly, which I did. I worked on a few simpler version to see if I understand the concept and now I come to this version.

The way the code is set up, everything will run properly other than 1 small error.  I can hit the "calculate" button on each notebook, and it will run the label and the model result from Pulp.  I can even hit the "forward" button and it will calculate with Pulp all the notebooks' printed result, but it will not display the "week 2"'s label.

I don't know where is the problem, or what code that I am missing, or code that i need edit with.

If someone can assist me, that would be great so I can get over this hump and use the same concept with my larger program.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial
import random
import pulp

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def  __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("notbook my own try")
        self.geometry("550x350")
        self.config(bg="tan")

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.lnb = Sheets(self) 

class Sheets(ttk.Notebook): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        parent.style.configure("down.TNotebook", tabposition="sw")
        super().__init__(parent, style = "down.TNotebook")
        self.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand =1)
        self.parent = parent

        self.week_index = ['Week 1', "Week 2"] 
        self.sheet_dict = {} 

        for num, week in enumerate(self.week_index, 1 ):
            self.week = One_Weekly_Notebook(self, num)
            self.week.pack()
            self.add(self.week, text = week)
            self.pack()
            self.sheet_dict[week] = self.week 

class One_Weekly_Notebook(ttk.Notebook): 
    def __init__(self, parent, index):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand =1)
        self.index = index
        self.parent = parent

        self.upper_tabs_dict = {}
        self.labelVariable_list = []
        self.label_list = []
        self.Var_list = []
        self.dropMenu_list = []
        self.answer_list = []
        self.model_list = []

        self.optionList=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
        self.optionList_random = []

        self.object_final = Final(self)
        tab1 = self.object_final 
        tab1.pack()

        self.add(tab1, text = "Final")
        self.pack()
        self.upper_tabs_dict["Final"] = tab1

    def pulp_process(self, button):
        self.a_value = int(self.parent.sheet_dict[f'Week  
                    {button}'].Var_list[0].get()) #1st dropdown value
        self.b_value= int(self.parent.sheet_dict[f'Week 
                    {button}'].Var_list[1].get())  #2nd dropdown value

    # Instantiate our problem class
        self.model = pulp.LpProblem("Profit maximising problem", 
                   pulp.LpMaximize)
        self.A = pulp.LpVariable('A', lowBound=0, cat='Integer') 
        self.B = pulp.LpVariable('B', lowBound=0, cat='Integer') 

    # Objective function
        self.model += (self.a_value * self.A ) + (self.b_value * 
                    self.B), "Profit"

    # Constraints
        self.model += 3 * self.A + 4 * self.B <= 3
        self.model += 5 * self.A + 6 * self.B <= 6
        self.model += 1.5 * self.A + 3 * self.B <= 2

    # Solve the problem
        self.model.solve()
        self.answer= pulp.value(self.model.objective)


    def see_label(self, button):
        self.parent.sheet_dict[f"Week  
        {button}"].label_list[0].configure
        (text = self.parent.sheet_dict[
                            f"Week {button}"].answer)

class Final(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.parent = parent

        self.labels()
    def labels(self):
        self.label=tk.Label(self, bg="orange", fg="white")
        self.label.pack()
        self.parent.label_list.append(self.label)

        self.random()
    def random(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self.random = random.choice(self.parent.optionList)
            self.parent.optionList_random.append(self.random)

        self.dropdowns()
    def dropdowns(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self.Var = tk.StringVar()
            self.dropMenu=tk.OptionMenu(self, self.Var, 
                          *self.parent.optionList)
            self.dropMenu.config(width = 10)
            self.dropMenu.pack(side = "left")

            self.parent.Var_list.append(self.Var)
            self.parent.dropMenu_list.append(self.dropMenu)


            self.parent.Var_list[i].set
                      (self.parent.optionList_random[i])

        self.buttons()
    def buttons(self):
        value = self.parent.index
        self.button=tk.Button(self, text="calculate")
        self.button.pack(side = "left")
        self.button.configure(command= lambda button=value: 
                    self.parent.pulp_process(button))

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Forward", command =  
                      self.forward)
        self.button.pack ()

    def forward(self):
        self.parent.pulp_process(1)
        self.parent.pulp_process(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().mainloop()
```

When I hit the "forward" button, it should show the pulp results onto the label in all the weeks together.

Comment: If you provide a [mcve], you'll have more chances to get an answer!

Comment: This code does not run. Please fix code indentation and linebreaks.

Comment: @Gsk hi, I reduced a much as I can already on the code.  I am still keep trying on my own, but if I reduce even more then it's an entirely different set up.

Comment: @figbeam, hi, it has pulp module in it.  the code run because it runs on my IDE.  did you download all the necessary modules?

Comment: Got an error even before loading modules. There are syntax errors.

Comment: @figbeam hi, what about now?  i realigned one line.  this is written in 3.6, just in case.  if you can tell me where there is an syntax error, it would be great.  It runs on my Atom IDE. thanks again.

Comment: I figured it out now.  I didn't have to to put "self.answer" into a list. I can just pass it through as the label text.  everything that I wanted to work is working now.  Thanks for the answer the question.